Me too or you too

‎I'm looking forward to seeing you.
↓
Me too. 〇


Nice talking to you.
↓
(nice talking to) You too.〇


I'm looking forward to seeing you too.
↓
You too. ☓

Why is "You too" wrong?

Who said it's wrong? Did you ask them why? What research have you done?

I suggest this Question belongs better in English Language Learning but since you're here, please consider your examples in more detail.
'I'm looking forward to seeing you.
↓
'Me too', is one construction, and wholly acceptable.
'Nice talking to you.
↓
'(nice talking to) You too', is a wholly different construction with no apparent justification. Please why, here, is that presented as '(nice talking to) You too', rather than the much more obvious 'Nice talking to you, too'?
Are you Asking here about one without the other, or the two together?
'I'm looking forward to seeing you too.
↓
'You too. ☓…' as presented here, could never work; not even if the final 'x' was meant as a kiss. Was it, please?
Please ask follow-up Questions and at first sight sorry; none of that works nor belongs in ELU, rather than ELL.
